# Select string based on certain word's presence only and exclude everything else

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a table like this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Apple Orange Car |
| 2 | 5 | Apple Tree |
| 3 | 8 | Apple Orange |
| 4 | 7 | Sun Orange |
| 5 | 8 | Orange |
| 6 | 7 | Apple Orange Apple |

Now what I want is to filter this DataFrame by **Text column** with either (**Apple** or **Orange**) present within a text there and nothing else.

So the output should look like this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 8 | Apple Orange |
| 5 | 8 | Orange |
| 6 | 7 | Apple Orange Apple |

What would be the way to achieve it?

Comment: Is this using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This breaks the words into a list, makes the list into a set, and then uses set operations to essentially ask:

- "Is the `Text` set a subset of `{'Apple', 'Orange'}`"

```
df[df.Text.str.split().apply(set).le({'Apple', 'Orange'})]
```

Output:

```
   Column1  Column2                Text
2        3        8        Apple Orange
4        5        8              Orange
5        6        7  Apple Orange Apple
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Tested it on the original data and it worked! Thank you and thanks for the explanation as well!